# phpmailer: how can I avoid bounce?

Tags: phpmailer, email-bounces

I use phpmailer. how can I avoid bounce? I already tried to set a bounce mail address, but I do not want to send bounces to any address.

Comment: What do you want to happen to messages that can't be delivered then?

Comment: nothing (no bounce mail)

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to send SMTP email, and not provide a mechanism for remote mailers to send bounces where users are not found. All SMTP email is sent from one email address to a set of recipients - that mail server can choose to accept the the email for onward delivery, or reject the message outright. If it accepts the message for onward delivery, and it later gets rejected then a bounce message may be generated, either to the original sender, or to the bounce recipient, if specified (and supported by the remote mailer).

To minimise the number of bounces, you could look up the MX record for each recipient domain, and try and handle the SMTP exchange yourself, and handle send errors appropriately (e.g. remove the recipient from your database, etc.)